# Get the first numbers from a String on Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

Suppose I have a String which begins with a number. 
How can I get/extract all the first numbers and convert them to an Integer? Don't want all the numbers on the String, I want the numbers since the first one until the last one before any other letter or character.

For example:

```
 String s= "5634-abofrda/+l8908"; // 5634
 String str="78695t08675jgk"; // 78695
```

How do I get the number 5634? 
I'm looking for a general solution, not specific for the cases decribed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method can be used to return a number before another character is found

```
static int getNumbers(String s) {

    String[] n = s.split(""); //array of strings
    StringBuffer f = new StringBuffer(); // buffer to store numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        if((n[i].matches("[0-9]+"))) {// validating numbers
            f.append(n[i]); //appending
        }else {
            //parsing to int and returning value
            return Integer.parseInt(f.toString()); 
        }   
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Usage:

```
getNumbers(s);
getNumbers(str);
```

Output:

```
5634
78695
```

Comment: It won't work for String without letters like for example: 12345. That code will return 0. If you want to make it work you need to add that line above return 0; statement...
if(f.length() > 0) return Integer.parseInt(f.toString());

Answer (score 7):

Use a *regular expression*. Match and group digits followed by anything and replace everything with the matched group. Like,

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\d+).+", "$1"));
```

Prints (as requested)

```
5634
```

Comment: This solution is cool, but it fails if the input string only contains digits. Use "(\\d+).*" to avoid cutting of the last digit.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option might be to just use `String#split`:

```
String s = "5634-abofrda/+l8908";
String nums = s.split("-")[0];
```

Note that in the case that a hyphen should not appear in the input string, then `nums` would just be the entire string.

Or perhaps you want this:

```
String s = "5634-abofrda/+l8908";
String nums = s.split("(?=\\D)")[0];
```

The lookahead `(?=\D)` will split the string everytime there is a non digit character.  This would leave the leading digits in the first string of the split array.

Comment: ty but in fact I was looking for something more general. Your solution works but only  if I had an "-" separating them.

Comment: @eyelash Um...if there is no logic to separate the numbers from everything else, then how can we answer?

Comment: I want to stop the 'separation' process when there's a Char that is not a digit. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, on your last solution the [0] means it starts on the first position ? So in your first solution if there was more than one "-" the result would be a String array?

Comment: The result will always be the first string in an array.

Comment: So what does the zero mean? Sorry but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right.

Comment: The `[0]` just means take the first string from the string array, that's it.